# How use toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to bind item with mouseover and mouseleave to highlight function which I created. My script doesn't work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#evtTarget").bind("mouseover", highlight);
  $("#evtTarget").bind("mouseleave", highlight);
});

function highlight(evt) {
  $("#evtTarget").toggleClass(highlighted);
}
```

```css
.normal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: Yellow;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Binding and Unbinding Events with jQuery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Binding Event Example</h1>
  <div id="evtTarget" class="normal">Mouse over this div to see the effect. Click on it to unbind the mouseover.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The console shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: highlighted is not defined", which shows us exactly where the problem is -- although it takes a little intuition and/or research to see exactly *what* the problem is.

Comment: can you search by the google for toggle class using keyword "jquery toggle class" select one solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, You forgot the `""` in `$("#evtTarget").toggleClass(highlighted);`

It should be `$("#evtTarget").toggleClass("highlighted");`

**Demo**

```js
function highlight() {
  $("#evtTarget").toggleClass("highlighted");
}

$(function() {
  $("#evtTarget").bind("mouseover", highlight);
  $("#evtTarget").bind("mouseleave", highlight);
});
```

```css
.normal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: Yellow;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Binding Event Example</h1>
<div id="evtTarget" class="normal">Mouse over this div to see the effect. Click on it to unbind the mouseover.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your logic is because `highlighted` needs to be provided to the `toggleClass()` method as a string:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#evtTarget").bind("mouseover", highlight);
  $("#evtTarget").bind("mouseleave", highlight);
});

function highlight(evt) {
  $("#evtTarget").toggleClass('highlighted');
}
```

```css
.normal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: Yellow;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Binding Event Example</h1>
<div id="evtTarget" class="normal">Mouse over this div to see the effect. Click on it to unbind the mouseover.</div>
```

That being said, there is absolutely no need for any JS or jQuery here as you can achieve the same effect more effectively (and with better performance) by using the `:hover` pseudo selector in CSS:

```css
.normal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: Yellow;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

#evtTarget:hover {
  background-color: Red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Binding Event Example</h1>
<div id="evtTarget" class="normal">Mouse over this div to see the effect. Click on it to unbind the mouseover.</div>
```

If you want to implement the behaviour noted in the text of the `div`, where the hover behaviour is disabled when the `div` itself is clicked on, you could add a class to the element and then make the CSS rule specific enough so that `:hover` does not override it, something like this:

```js
$('#evtTarget').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('disable-hover');
});
```

```css
.normal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: Yellow;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

#evtTarget:hover {
  background-color: Red;
}

#evtTarget.disable-hover {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Binding Event Example</h1>
<div id="evtTarget" class="normal">Mouse over this div to see the effect. Click on it to unbind the mouseover.</div>
```

Comment: "Click on it to unbind the mouseover" doesn't work, but that's not really the important part.

Comment: That's true, although the OP hadn't implemented it. I'll add a note about it - thanks.